# Python Pandas remove items from list in one column from the list in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns that both contain lists of strings. df['col1'] and df['col2]. I am trying to remove in each row all the items contained in col2's list from col1's list and make a new column. For example:

```
col1           col2         col3
[a, b, c]     [a, b]        [c]
[a, c, f, d]  [a, f]        [c, d]    
[d, c, e, f]  [d, e, f, c]  []
```

Comment: @miles You must be more specific in asking your question. You need to better describe your problem then show the code you used propose to solve your issue. S.O. is best used for code related reproducible questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own function to create the new lists and then use `apply` on the dataframe to execute the function for each row like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'f', 'd'], ['d', 'c', 'e', 'f']], 
                   'col2':[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'c']]})

def func(df):
    return list(set(df['col1']) - set(df['col2']))

df['col3'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

The function converts the lists to sets and uses set subtraction to remove values contained in `col2` from `col1`.

Comment: wow thanks. I didn't realize you could subtract sets of strings. This is super helpful